# Implementation of Volvos Innovation Portal API

Tags: c#, api, openid-connect

Has anyone successfully implemented the Volvo API (https://developer.volvocars.com/volvo-api/connected-vehicle/)? If so have any examples?

The API documentation in regards to the authorization part seems to be lacking a bit. I'm trying to access my vehicles information from C#, and so far I've figured out that they are using OpenID with oauth2.

I've tried using the IdentityModel library, and with this I can log in by using the "RequestPasswordTokenAsync()" towards the token endpoint I found by checking the network traffic when signing in. This gives me an access_token, but it's not the valid access_token for requesting API calls.

Other than that I'm quite lost. I would appreciate any help